# How to define screen reader sequence for a web page

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I'm working on an accessibility task for a mobile web app (HTML+Angular+ARIA). I tested some potential ways:

1. `aria-flowto` and `aria-owns`, not working for web page
2. `tabIndex`, not working

In my local test with iOS 9.2.1 Safari, the default screen reader is linear way from top. Is there a way I can define elements reading order? Like [what `aria-flowto` is doing](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-flowto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-flowto` is supposed to provide this sort of functionality (and it is the only proposed way to do so) but it has not been implemented yet by AT vendors (or by browsers for keyboard-only access).

As such, the only thing you can do is to ensure that the order of the elements in the DOM is the order that is natural for a screen reader to read the page.

Comment: Adding to this answer in case someone else is looking. JAWS 17 apparently supports it. As far as my research went, no other AT supports this still - JAWS ref link https://www.freedomscientific.com/downloads/JAWS/jaws17features