# If tabindex is already occupied, it should skip it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am practicing on some keyboard features and I just looked at tabIndex in AngularJS.
I am having a little problem that if my text boxes which have tab index value 1, 2 and 3 are already occupied by some values while I am focussing on tabIndex 1, it should skip the tabIndex 2 and 3 and should focus at tabIndex 4 when I press the tab button next time.
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller = "TestApp">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="1">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="2">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="3">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="4">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="5">
<input ng-model="m1" tabindex="6">
</div>
```

When I manually enter the values in textbox 1, 2 and 3 and click on textbox 1 again and then press tab, it should navigate to tabindex 4 instead of navigating to tabindex 1 again.
Your help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: why all models are same??

Comment: My texboxes can have the same valuein them. My focus is on tabindex not on ng-model.

Comment: I think there is no other way but JavaScript. Basically you need to catch the tab press, then check which input has focus, get the next input and check its value and if there is value skip that input and focus the next input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define screen reader sequence for a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146254/how-to-define-screen-reader-sequence-for-a-web-page)